# Package pstricks doesn't work

Tags: pstricks, overleaf, pstricks-add

I am working on overleaf, but when I add `\usepackage{pstricks}` doesn't compile

In addition, when I compile with the package appear what you see in the image. Any idea?
[image: Error when compiles without the pstricks]

The code I used is the following

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno,draft]{amsbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{rawfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphics}
%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\newcommand{\lm}{\text{\rm lím\;}}
\newcommand{\sen}{\text{\;\rm sen\;}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\text{\;\rm tg\;}}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12.2cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{18cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{6mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.2cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\newpsobject{grilla}{psgrid}{subgriddiv=1,griddots=10}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(8,6)(-10,-6)
%\grilla
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](-10,0)(6,0)
\psarc[linewidth=1pt](-4,0){3.5}{90}{270}
\psarc[linewidth=1pt](-4,0){4}{90}{270}
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-4,4)(5,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-4,3.5)(5,3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-4,-4)(5,-4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-4,-3.5)(5,-3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1pt](5,4)(5,3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1pt](5,-4)(5,-3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(5.1,3.75)(6,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(5.1,-3.75)(6,-3.75)
\rput{45}(-1.2,2.8){\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed]{->}(-4,0)(-4,3.5)}
\psline[linewidth=2pt](-6,3)(-7,2) \uput[l](7,3.75){$f$}
\uput[l](7,-3.75){$f$} \uput[u](-4,4){$A$} \uput[d](-4,-4){$B$}
\uput[l](-4.2,1.5){$p$} \uput[u](-6,0){$\theta$}
\psarc[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt
3pt](-4,0){1.7}{135}{180}
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed](5,5)(5,-5)
\uput[u](5.5,4){$A'$} \uput[d](5.5,-4){$B'$} \uput[d](-9,0){$X$}
\uput[d](6,0){$X$} \put(-0.3,-5){$(a)$}
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(0,1.5)(0,3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(-2,1.5)(-2,3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(2,1.5)(2,3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(4,1.5)(4,3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(0,-1.5)(0,-3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(-2,-1.5)(-2,-3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(2,-1.5)(2,-3.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(4,-1.5)(4,-3.5)

\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PStricks doesn't work with pdfLaTeX.  Try changing the compiler to XeLaTeX

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik it works :D

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot